# Как сделать чтение в си без задержки?

Tags: c, разработка-игр

Пишу игру платформер на стандартных библиотеках си. Нужно считывать данные в переменную (скен-коды клавиш), но функция getch() делает задержку. Можно ли в си использовать чтение без задержки?

Comment: Можно, но это *системозависимо* (в каждой ОС по разному)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это возможно. Но есть риск получить платформенно зависимое решение. Итак, варианты

- использовать специфические функции ([kbhit](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/posix-kbhit?view=vs-2019)).
- использовать отдельный поток, который будет читать стандартный ввод, складывать в очередь. А уже основной код будет подчитывать по мере необходимости.
- использовать [select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html). И тут даже есть два варианта - сделать функцию опроса клавиатуры или полноценный цикл.
- использовать готовые движки, к примеру, [ncurse](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/)

Достаточно подробно раскрыто [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717572/how-do-you-do-non-blocking-console-i-o-on-linux-in-c)

Comment: Для \*nix-ов я бы в первую очередь посоветовал почитать [man 3 termios/tcgetattr/tcsetattr](http://ru.manpages.org/termios/3)